# Why should I observe a limit of sixteen partitions per disk with OS X?

Tags: macos, partition

I read things such as:

- Mac OS X may be unstable with more than sixteen partitions
- up to sixteen partitions on a external drive.

Also I understand that in a sixteen-slice environment, the full installer for OS X Mountain Lion may be unable to add an `Apple_Boot` slice for Recovery OS.

## If there's a limit

Why the number 16?

---

### References

Red Hat Bugzilla Bug 460390 – Can't make apple boot partition catch 22 during install (netinstall CD): [comment 8](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=460390#c8) (2008-11-15)

> … more than 16 partitions on the drive … Mac OS X did boot with the 
>   whole drive formatted (as several partitions), or with more than 16 partitions, 
>   but it did not recognize the entire drive, and may not have been stable. …

[.Drives, partitions, formatting w/Mac's + PC's: Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3044) (2012-12-05)

> … up to 16 partitions on a external drive …

Answer (score 5):

A maximum of sixteen partitions per GPT disk may be for one or both of the following:

- compatibility with other BSD variants
- UNIX certification/conformance.

### Key points

In theory, a GUID Partition Table (GPT) disk can have an unlimited number of partitions.

A Microsoft implementation of GPT allows a maximum of 128 partitions.

The OS X kernel, libraries, and utilities are drawn from a number of open source projects, including FreeBSD, GNU, NetBSD, and OpenBSD.

Some BSD variants have a maximum of sixteen partitions.

#### Sometimes misunderstood

[Mac OS X: Mac OS Extended format (HFS Plus) volume and file limits](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2422)

> **Volume and file limits in Mac OS X**
>
> Maximum number of volumes (all Mac OS X versions): no limit …

That is:

- volumes per operating system
- not partitions per disk.

Expect the operating system to handle:

- thirty-two or more volumes spread across two or more disks
- and so on.

---

### Further reading

[disklabel(8) OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/disklabel.8.html) (2004-09-03)

[Frequently asked questions about the GUID Partitioning Table disk architecture](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302873) (2009-08-04)

> …The Microsoft implementation of GUID Partition Table is limited to 128 partitions. …

[OS X Glossary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/SLGlobalGlossary/Glossary/Glossary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008752-BK01_CH02-BK01_CH02_LK00001) (2010-07-09)

> **BSD** 
>   Berkeley Software Distribution. Formerly known as the Berkeley version of UNIX, 
>   BSD is now simply called the BSD operating system. The BSD portion of Darwin is 
>   based on 4.4BSD Lite 2 and FreeBSD, a flavor of 4.4BSD.

[Unix 03 Conformance Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Darwin/RN-Unix03Conformance/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004772) (2010-09-01)

> … FreeBSD, GNU, NetBSD, and OpenBSD … make an effort to 
>   follow industry standards …

[www.bsd.org](http://www.bsd.org/) (2011-03-30)

[How-To Dual Boot FreeBSD, Linux, and OpenBSD with GNU Grub](http://geodsoft.com/howto/dualboot/) (undated but Copyright © 2000 - 2012)

> … OpenBSD's disklabel allows up to 16 partitions. …

Register of Open Branded Products: [five product standards for which Mac OS X Version 10.8 Mountain Lion is registered](http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/apple.htm) (2012-07-10)

[BSD disklabel – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_disklabel) (2013-01-27)

> … BSD disklabels traditionally contain 8 entries for describing partitions. 
>   These are, by convention, labeled alphabetically, 'a' through to 'h'. Some 
>   BSD variants have since increased this to 16 partitions, labeled 'a' through to 'p'. …